# Error: [$injector:itkn] in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am making simple demo in angularJS and i am ran into below problem:

```
Error: [$injector:itkn] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/itkn?p0=function%20productCategoryService(%24http)
H/<@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:6:416
e@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:40:458
h/<.invoke@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:41:86
ff/this.$get</</<@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:86:442
u@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:65:338
g@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:58:136
M/<@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:57:279
Ac/c/</<@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:21:84
uf/this.$get</m.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:141:43
uf/this.$get</m.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:141:275
Ac/c/<@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:21:42
h/<.invoke@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:41:293
Ac/c@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:20:1
Ac@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:21:259
fe@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:20:69
@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:306:372
x.Callbacks/c@http://localhost:3000/javascripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4:26031
x.Callbacks/p.fireWith@http://localhost:3000/javascripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4:26840
.ready@http://localhost:3000/javascripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4:3303
q@http://localhost:3000/javascripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4:715

http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js
Line 114
```

Module:

```
(function(){
    var productCategoryModule = angular.module("productCategoryModule", []);  
})();
```

Controller:

```
angular.module("productCategoryModule")
    .controller("productCategoryController", productCategoryController);

//dependency injection
productCategoryController.$inject = ['$scope', '$timeout', productCategoryService];

    function productCategoryController($scope, $timeout, productCategoryService) {

        $scope.productCategory = {
            categoryName : "",
            categoryDetails : ""
        };

        $scope.createProductCategory = function(productCategory) {        
            productCategoryService.createProductCategory(productCategory).then(function (data) {
                alert("Category has been created successfully.");
            });        
        };
    }
```

And Service is as below:

```
angular.module("productCategoryModule")
    .factory("productCategoryService", productCategoryService);

productCategoryService.$inject = ['$http'];

function productCategoryService($http) {

  return {
      createProductCategory : function(productCategory) {
          console.log("In Service");

          return $http.post("/createProductCategory",
              {
                  categoryName: productCategory.categoryName,
                  details: productCategory.categoryDetails
              }
          );
      }
  };
}
```

View is working fine but when i added above code then it's giving above error. I am not getting what wrong am i doing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`productCategoryService` should be in quotes while you are using `$inject`.

```
productCategoryController.$inject = ['$scope', '$timeout', 'productCategoryService'];
```